# AS3 looping an IF statement

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have created a loop, inside there is an if statment but it doesnt seem to execute more than once, but the same loop instead with a WHILE statment works but i really need to be an if statement.

```
function lines ()
{
    for( SS = 0; SS < 11; SS++)
    {
        while(freq1.text == slotCheck+SS && freq4.text == slotCheck+SS )
        {
            freq2.text = "Win"; 
            break;
        }
```

The above works but i need the below one to execute 11 times.

```
function lines ()
{
    for( SS = 0; SS < 11; SS++)
    {
        if(freq1.text == slotCheck+SS && freq4.text == slotCheck+SS )
        {
            freq2.text = "Win"; 
            break;
        }
```

Comment: break will exit the loop. why exactly do you need an if statement?

Comment: if(freq1.text == slotCheck+SS && freq4.text == slotCheck+SS && freq6.text == slotCheck+SS)else if freq1.text == slotCheck+SS && freq4.text == slotCheck+SS{
so i can have an else if statment aswell

Comment: this actually much looks like AS2 :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was my Pc, when i had restarted my machine everything was fine again. the loops and the code are correct anyways so my fustration was a hardware issue, (RAM) got plenty of it but its faulty as im experiencing missing files at random related to ram

sorry to have confused you guys

Answer (score 1):

I dont get your question???

You can just remove the `Break;` statement and your loop will be executed  11 times.

Comment: No, if(freq1.text == slotCheck+SS && freq4.text == slotCheck+SS ){
     the above have to be true to break the loop, but whats happening that its not checking this if statment 11 times it only checking it once.

Answer (score 1):

I think I get your question now.

You need to change 'break' to 'continue' to get it to run 11 times, and still skip other conditionals.